# Change default fonts in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there a way of changing the default fonts in Microsoft Edge?

In particular, it looks like the default monospace font in Edge is Courier New. How do I make it use Consolas instead?

(There's a Settings menu item to change the style and font size, but that applies only to Reading view.)

Comment: Just curious: are there still websites that depend on default fonts? You might be looking at the wrong place for your problem.

Comment: @Arjan Well, on Wikipedia for example, fixed-width text uses Courier New on Edge, and Consolas on Chrome. This includes typewriter text and the editing window. The HTML help pages in R are also minimally formatted, and use whatever defaults your browser has.

Comment: Ah, you're right; Wikipedia uses `.mw-code{ font-family: monospace, Courier }`, so would first take the default and otherwise request Courier (which I think would not be used in any browser, as all browsers will understand `monospace`). Weird stylesheet, I'd think.